# How do I cut down a bathroom wall drain?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, sink

I am doing a minor renovation on our second bathroom, and I have run into a problem.

I was able to remove the old vanity,mirror, etc., and repair the drywall. The water valves both leaked, so I removed and replaced both of those. The new vanity (Godmorgon from Ikea) is installed, but now I've run into a slight problem.

The drawer for the vanity hits the wall drain, with about an inch needed for clearance, plus whatever is needed for installing the drain piping from the sink. Also, the drain piping that came with the sink (Also from Ikea) is much smaller than the wall piping.

I've attached 3 photos of what it looks like, where do I go from here?

Wall piping with Ikea tubing

[image]

Wall piping:

[image]

Drawer needing clearance:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You'd need to reduce the entrance (easy, fittings are made) and RAISE the pipe in the wall (possible but a relatively huge amount of work/expense.) So I'm not quite sure what you mean with "cut down" the drain pipe.

As shown in the pictures, I'm inclined to say cut a notch in the back of the drawer for pipe clearance, and get the reducer you need to go from the drain you have to the tailpiece (the Ikea plumbing you have.)

Alternatively, cut as much as you need off the base of the vanity unit, but if you've already mounted it, that will be a pain, and if you like the height of the countertop now, it would change.

**Responding to comment** - if it's glued ABS pipe (as I would appear to be) you'd cut it off at the back of the fitting that's on there and glue on an elbow - there appears to be enough pipe behind the fitting to do that. If threaded, you'd unscrew the fitting and screw on an elbow. Reduced or not reduced it will run into the drawer if going straight out. I'm unclear where you are going to fit plumbing and traps with two drawers evidently in the space they'll need, unless there's some sort of room off to one side.

**Additional note:** - you really should fill in around those water pipes. That type of convenient opening into the back of cabinets is loved by The Uninvited Guests That Travel and/or Live In The Walls.

Comment: Cut down, reduce the amount it sticks out from the wall. Raising it wouldn't help, as there is another drawer that goes above the one pictured.

Comment: This vanity was obviously not designed by a plumber, and I was a little surprised that none of the assembly documents provided by Ikea offer any help for something as fundamental as having the thing not drain out onto the floor. There are some [good pictures available](http://www.housetweaking.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/vanity-8.jpg) of other people's installations of this thing though.

Comment: @Comintern - That picture helps immensely. If I can run it all to the side like that then I have enough room. And yes, the kit that came with the sink has all of the attachments.

Answer (score 1):

These units are designed for the exact application you have. The white pipe in your picture is designed to be used with the special telescoping waste tee assembly that should have been included with the unit. The picture @Comintern linked to is the way you must plumb it. You will need to carefully remove the fittings that are attached to the pipe coming out of the wall, if they are glued on you will use a hacksaw blade and cut just behind that coupling. Then glue on a 1 1/2" slip-joint adapter

[image]

Then install an 1 1/2" slip-joint trap configured like in @Comintern's link.

[image]

If the pipe coming out of the wall is threaded, use a SJ nut and washer to attach the trap directly to it.